# updating Jetpack Compose UI from SQL Connector through ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mssql-jdbc

I have a price checker app. that requests the details of a product using its barcode.
very simple.. i'm only in the first page.

I created the UI and SQL query and I can get the data from the server, however, I can't update the UI. there is something I'm not doing right for sure. but I'm still learning Kotlin so please be patient with me.

The function that request and display the data is this

```
@Composable
fun PriceChecker(viewModel: MainViewModel,context: Context) {
    var barcode by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(250.dp)) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(500.dp)
                .border(width = 2.dp, color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
        ) {
            TextField(
                onValueChange = {
                    barcode = it
                },
                value = barcode,
                singleLine = true,
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = ({
                    //hidekeyboard
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                  
  //get product details
                    viewModel.getDetails(barcode) <-- this
                  
                    //erasing text after sending barcode
                    barcode = ""
                })),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
            )
            Text(text = viewModel.name) <-- needed value from SQLthrough ViewModel
            Text(text = viewModel.price)<-- needed value from SQL through ViewModel
        }
    }
}
```

In the viewmodel i have this simply

```
class MainViewModel:ViewModel() {

    var price= RepositorySQL().price


    var name = RepositorySQL().name


    fun getDetails(barcode:String){
        RepositorySQL().getProductDetails(barcode)
    }
}
```

i tried to use the `mutablestateof()` for the values but it also didn't update the UI

In the Sql connector i have it this way:

```
 var price by mutableStateOf("Product Name") //also var price = ""
    private set
    var name by mutableStateOf("Product Price") //also var name = ""
    private set

    val cls ="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    var connection: Connection? = null


    fun getProductDetails(barcode: String){
        val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
        Class.forName(cls)
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(newUrl, newUser, newPass)
        if (connection!=null){
            val statement = connection!!.createStatement()
            val result = statement.executeQuery("Select [ItemName],[Price] FROM [twisted].[dbo].[Inventory] WHERE [ItemNum] = '$barcode';")
            while (result.next()){
                name =  result.getString("ItemName")
                price = result.getDouble("Price").toString()
                Log.d(TAG, "Product name = ${name}") //values are printed correctly.
                Log.d(TAG, "Product Price = ${price}")//values are printed correctly.
                }
        }else{
            name = "Didn't get any data"
            Log.d(TAG, name)
        }
    }
```

the UI remains the same even when I update the values... I'm sure that the solution should be easy but I'm still learning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you're creating `RepositorySQL()` on each line, that's gonna be all different objects

In your `RepositorySQL` you're using `mutableStateOf` with delegation. This makes `price` and `name` in `MainViewModel` plain strings, not states, so they're not gonna watch `RepositorySQL` values

To make `MutableState` `private set` you had to declare private `MutableState` and public `State`, like this:

```
class RepositorySQL {
    private val _price = mutableStateOf("Product Name")
    val price: State<String> = _price

    private val _name = mutableStateOf("Product Price")
    val name: State<String> = _name

    fun getProductDetails(t: String) {
        _price.value = "1"
        _name.value = "2"
    }
}
```

And in `MainViewModel` you can declare your values as delegates to `RepositorySQL`:

```
class MainViewModel:ViewModel() {
    private val repositorySQL = RepositorySQL()

    val price by repositorySQL.price

    val name by repositorySQL.name

    fun getDetails(barcode:String){
        repositorySQL.getProductDetails(barcode)
    }
}
```

Comment: When we use stuff with delegation inside the viewmodel, they are still treated as state. You only need to initialise the var with `MutableState<T>` type with/without delegation, and it will always trigger recompositions. Remember when in the State Codelab they use delegation in the viewmodel to initialise the core variable for the todo app? The list

Comment: Ok now they are using `mutableStateListOf` instead, which does not require delegation, but at the time I took it, they did use `var todoItems by mutableStateOf(listOf<TodoItem>())`, and did not have to call `.value` time and again. Test it

Comment: But the problem could lie in the fact that he is not directly using that variable inside a composable, but in fact he is using the viewmodel as an intermediate, possibly causing a connectivity break. If he could actually return `LiveData` from the SQL Connector instead, it would work like a charm

Comment: okey that worked. thank you so much... i didn't know about this before... but one question--> Can't i use one public state in ```RepositorySQL()``` and this is it?

Comment: @KotlinStudent you can make `MutableState` public but then it'll be possible to modify it from outside which is not very good. No way to make `private set` without two props

Comment: @MARSK you can use delegation inside your view model, which is what I am doing here, but KotlinStudent used it in `RepositorySQL` which cannot work, this is one more data layer